# Smarty Template Engine - Unload/Disallow plugins while using $smarty->fetch

Tags: php, smarty, smarty-plugins

How can I unload or disallow smarty core plugins from a template when using `$smarty->fetch('mytemplate.tpl')` method

For example the template `mytemplate.tpl` contains **{html_options}** and **{html_table}**

When using `$smarty->fetch('mytemplate.tpl')` only the **{html_options}** should be parsed by smarty, but **{html_table}** not

removing the `function.html_table.php` from plugin folder is not an option as it is still in use by another `$smarty->fetch()` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solutions is to extend from the `Smarty_Security` class and enable securty by using the method

`$smarty->enableSecurity($instanceOfClass)`

Once the fetch method has been called , `disableSecurity` method do the trick to reenable all `plugins/tags/modifiers` again.

**Unfortunately when enableSecurity is used and forbidden functions are used an Exception is thrown**

An alternative is to replace all tags/variables/... you want to disallow with **{literal}{forbiddenTags}{/literal}** by using `preg_replace` **before calling** `$smarty->fetch([...])`

Example

```
# negate regular expression pattern to allow only the below tags
$pattern = "/\{(?!allowedTag1|allowedTag2).*?\}/";
$replacement = '{literal}$0{/literal}';

$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
$smarty->fetch("string:" . $content);
```

More details about the Security class here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl